# Can I bypass UIActivityViewController but still somehow use its target-specific share logic?

Tags: ios, facebook

I've got my app sharing just fine through UIActivityViewController, but I want to instead add explicit Facebook, Twitter, etc. share buttons to my interface. What I want is to bypass the UIActivityViewController popover that allows you to pick the share target, say Facebook, and instead go straight to the same share mechanism that UIActivityViewContoller goes to when you hit its Facebook button. I just don't see any documentation for how to do that.

I understand that I can recreate the mechanism entirely, but I don't want that. I'm sharing a video and using Charles (network traffic monitoring tool) I see that there are no less than 11 graph API calls during the entire process. Not to mention that I like the existing behavior if you're not logged into the FB app, don't have the FB app installed but are just logged in in the IOS settings, etc. I'd prefer to not recreate something that is already working perfectly for my purposes.

I have two reasons for wanting to bypass UIActivityViewController. First is to make the share buttons more accessible. Secondly is for efficiency: I've captured camera frames and share them as an animated gif for most targets but as a movie for Facebook (since FB can't handle animated gif). So the process of making the movie (which takes a couple of seconds) in response to the user activating UIActivityViewController is wasted unless the user shares to facebook. With the broken out share buttons I can avoid packaging the content for the other share targets unnecessarily.